# Url Rewriting of aspx page.pls give me suggestion

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am new in asp.net. I have iis version 6.0. I want to rewrite url. Actually I'm working on a site. When I used this tag in `web.config`

```
  <urlrewritingnet
    rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true"
    contextItemsPrefix="QueryString"
    defaultPage="default.aspx"
    defaultProvider="RegEx"
    xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07" >
    <rewrites>
      <add name="this-is-a-long-page-name"  virtualUrl="^~/this-is-a-long-page-name"
            rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
            destinationUrl="~/Default.aspx"
            ignoreCase="true" />
    </rewrites>
  </urlrewritingnet>
```

When I run it, it shows the error "unrecognized configuration section rewriter".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

user ,

you need to implement urlrewritemodule , all the requests comes to the urlrewritemodule.
you can write your logic there

```
public  class UrlModule : IHttpModule
    {
        public virtual void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(this.BaseUrlModule_BeginRequest);
        }
        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
        }
        protected virtual void BaseUrlModule_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            Rewritethepath(application.Request.Path, application);
        }

        private  void Rewritethepath(string requestedPath, HttpApplication application)
        {
           application.Context.RewritePath("/yournewurl", String.Empty, QueryString);                
        }
    }
```

make this entry in your web.config

```
<httpModules>
                <add type="namespace.UrlModule, namespace" name="UrlModule"/>
            </httpModules>
```

Register your httpmodule in your web.config , once everyrequest comes to this you can rewrite the url however you want ,

i recently implemented this and let me know if you need any help, I will defiently help you.

Comment: Pls tell me i have do any change in web.config

Comment: add httpModules in your configuration section and have this dll in the bin folder if it is a separate dll.

Comment: which dll.i dont know pls suggest me` <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>` i add this one in web.config it gives error

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'namespace' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. i added it` <add type="namespace.UrlModule, namespace" name="UrlModule"/>`

Comment: user , you should change namespace , with your library name , where did you define urlModule in your project , give that name here

Comment: k Intelligencia.UrlRewriter is the name of dll which i added it bin bin.and add same in web.config.pls review it.` <add type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.UrlModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" name="UrlModule"/>` it also gives error

Comment: `<add type="urlwriter.UrlModule, urlwriter" name="UrlModule"/>
,the namespace of urlmodule is urlWriter

Comment: @user ,i waited yesterday for your reply and left, is it working now.

Comment: no.bt i used other functionality.that is worked with iis5.0.but wid iis6.0 it is not worked

Answer (score 1):

My response doesn't directly answer your question (which is about the UrlRewritingNet library). Instead, I suggest considering Microsoft's official [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) library, which requires IIS 7.x or [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb). The UrlRewritingNet library, though useful a couple years ago, is now a less than ideal way to go about rewriting URLs in IIS/ASP.NET. I offer this suggestion since you mentioned you are new to ASP.NET. :)

Comment: I have iis6.0 .is it any way to rewriting url with iis6.0